# How to move a Grunt project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, gruntjs, project

Following problem:
There is a directory workspace with several Git projects in it. Until now I used Grunt only to improve my workflow and my "save-dev"-grunt environment is within the workspace folder. But now we want to use it within the Git projects (directories are within the workspace directory). So there has to be a grunt environment within every project folder. It seems that I can't install a new grunt environment within a project because a grunt environment within a grunt environment is not possible. So how to manage this? Would it be enough to move the Gruntfile.js, package.json and the node_modules folder into the projects and edit the paths within the Gruntfile.js and delete the non-project relevant tasks or is there more to be aware of?

And if other members of the team want to use the Grunt task does it suffice for them to install node and the Grunt Cli as global. Or is there more to consider?

Comment: Do you wan to do common tasks across workspace and specific tasks in project, I had done similar thing before a bit hacky way.

Comment: Specific tasks. But meanwhile I tested it. Removing the 2 Files and the folder mentioned above was enough. Afterwards I could install Grunt within the sub folder.